# How to enable virtualization in bios windows 8 using AMD E1-2100 APU G505?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, virtualization, bios, amd-processor

I am using lenovo AMD E1-2100 APU G505. I want to run a Virtual PC . After some googling I got some instruction. Some of the people suggested to change in bios. They suggested to go to **Bios-> Security -> System Security -> Enable virtual**. But when I tried that, I didn't find the **system security** under **Security**. what should I do? How can I enable virtualization in my pc? Please share If any one have any idea.

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](http://superuser.com).

Comment: Solved this by editing bios -> config -> SVM enable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by editing bios -> config -> SVM enable.